# Prepared Statement on Postgresql in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, prepared-statement

Right now I am in the middle of migrating from SQLite to Postgresql and I came across this problem. The following prepared statement works with SQLite:

```
id = 5
st = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection.prepare("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id = ?")
st.execute(id)
st.close
```

Unfortunately it is not working with Postgresql - it throws an exception at line 2.
I was looking for solutions and came across this:

```
id = 5
require 'pg'
conn = PG::Connection.open(:dbname => 'my_db_development')
conn.prepare('statement1', 'DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id = $1')
conn.exec_prepared('statement1', [ id ])
```

This one fails at line 3. When I print the exception like this

```
rescue => ex
```

ex contains this

```
{"connection":{}}
```

Executing the SQL in a command line works. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How can I find this out? I am asking because there is no output in the console regarding an exception.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want to use `prepare` like that then you'll need to make a couple changes:

1. The PostgreSQL driver wants to see numbered placeholders (`$1`, `$2`, ...) not question marks and you need to give your prepared statement a name:

   ```
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection.prepare('some_name', "DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id = $1")
   ```
2. The calling sequence is [`prepare`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Connection#prepare-instance_method) followed by [`exec_prepared`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Connection#exec_prepared-instance_method):

   ```
   connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection
   connection.prepare('some_name', "DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id = $1")
   st = connection.exec_prepared('some_name', [ id ])
   ```

The above approach works for me with ActiveRecord and PostgreSQL, your `PG::Connection.open` version should work if you're connecting properly.

Another way is to do the quoting yourself:

```
conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
conn.execute(%Q{
    delete from my_table
    where id = #{conn.quote(id)}
})
```

That's the sort of thing that ActiveRecord is usually doing behind your back.

Directly interacting with the database tends to be a bit of a mess with Rails since the Rails people don't think you should ever do it.

If you really are just trying to delete a row without interference, you could use [`delete`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-delete):

> **delete()**
>
> [...]
>
> The row is simply removed with an SQL `DELETE` statement on the record’s primary key, and no callbacks are executed.

So you can just say this:

```
MyTable.delete(id)
```

and you'll send a simple `delete from my_tables where id = ...` into the database.

Comment: You were right - giving the statement a name and using a dollar char instead of a question mark did the job. I am aware of the delete function - in this case I am deleting something from a joint table which does not have it's own model. Rather than creating one I went for a "quick" solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To complement an already accepted answer for anyone Googling prepared statements in Rails for custom queries, here is a simpler way to do it via existing ActiveRecord interface (example is for Postgresql):

```ruby
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query("select * from table_name where id = $1", 
"example_query", [1], prepare: true)
```

And if you put `binding.pry`, you will see that prepared statement is indeed created:

```ruby
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query('select * from pg_prepared_statements')
```

Reference: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4.2/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html