# How to check if my prepared statement in Rails is executing or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, prepared-statement

I have this prepared statement in Rails (postgres  db):

```rb
    conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection

    conn.prepare('query_fetch_dest_values',
       "SELECT q.entity AS source_entity,
          q.financial_institution AS source_financial_institution,
          q.account_number AS source_account_number,
          a2.entity AS destination_entity,
          a2.financial_institution AS destination_financial_institution,
          a2.account_number AS destination_account_number
        FROM
        (SELECT *
         FROM forecast_entry_and_cash_positions
         INNER JOIN accounts a ON forecast_entry_and_cash_positions.source_account_id = a.account_number 
         WHERE (input_type IN ($1) AND
            a.financial_institution IN ($2) AND
            forecast_entry_and_cash_positions.source_account_id IN ($3))
         )q LEFT JOIN accounts a2 ON q.dest_account_id = a2.account_number")

    search_destination_values = 
      conn.exec_prepared('query_fetch_dest_values',
        [decode_input_type(params[:search_input_type]),
          params[:search_source_financial_institution],
          params[:search_source_account_number]
        ])

    puts "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
    puts search_destination_values.inspect
```

1. The above SQL is not getting printed on my console. So how do I get to know if my query is being executed or not?
2. In the `inspect` as shown in above code, this is what is getting printed on the console:

```rb
#<PG::Result:0x00007f9d32c528b8 status=PGRES_TUPLES_OK ntuples=0 nfields=6 cmd_tuples=0>
```

I learnt from this blog - https://blog.kiprosh.com/understanding-pg-result-object/ that `nTuples=0` and `cmd_tuples=0` in the above output means the number of records returned by the SQL is 0.

My query in pgadmin returns 3 records - why am I not getting any output here?

3. This documentation https://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Connection#exec_prepared-instance_method and stackoverflow blogs like this one -> [Prepared Statement on Postgresql in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805627/prepared-statement-on-postgresql-in-rails) show how to pass dynamic values for filters when the filter condition is an `=` (equals) condition on the filtered columns.

However in my condition I have 3 `IN` filters. The documentation does not show an example for passing dynamic filters for `IN` clauses. In the above code snippet, is the way am passing dynamic filters for my 3 `IN` clauses correct? (Again, since my query is not getting printed on my console, I am unable to verify if my filters got added correctly to the SQL or not).

Comment: are doing that in a rails console ?. Try setting `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` and then execute statement, if you see it in the console, then it got executed.

Comment: I have the logger setup. I am able to see other queries getting printed in my app